# SQL Server: Count days difference between previous date and current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to find a way to count days difference between two dates from previous and current rows which counting only business days.

Example data and criteria here.

```
  ID        StartDate       EndDate         NewDate        DaysDifference
 ========================================================================
  0         04/05/2017      null       
  1         12/06/2017     16/06/2017      12/06/2017         29
  2         03/07/2017     04/07/2017      16/06/2017         13
  3         07/07/2017     10/07/2017      04/07/2017         5
  4         12/07/2017     26/07/2017      10/07/2017         13
```

My end goal is
I want two new columns; NewDate and DayDifference.

- NewDate column is from EndDate from previous row. As you can see that for example, NewDate of ID 2 is 16/06/2017 which come from EndDate of ID 1. But if value in EndDate of previous row is null, use its StartDate instead(ID 1 case).
- DaysDifference column is from counting only business days between EndDate and NewDate columns.

Here is script that I am using atm.

```
    select distinct
    c.ID
    ,c.EndDate
    ,isnull(p.EndDate,c.StartDate) as NewDate
    ,count(distinct cast(l.CalendarDate as date)) as DaysDifference

    from    
                (select *
                from table) c
                full join
                (select *
                from table) p
                on c.level = p.level
                and c.id-1 = p.id           

    left join Calendar l
    on (cast(l.CalendarDate as date) between cast(p.EndDate as date) and cast(c.EndDate as date)
    or 
    cast(l.CalendarDate as date) between cast(p.EndDate as date) and cast(c.StartDate as date))
    and l.Day not in ('Sat','Sun') and l.Holiday <> 'Y'

    where c.ID <> 0 
    group by 
    c.ID
    ,c.EndDate
    ,isnull(p.EndDate,c.StartDate)
```

And this's the current result :

```
  ID        EndDate         NewDate        DaysDifference
 =========================================================
  1         16/06/2017      12/06/2017         0
  2         04/07/2017      16/06/2017         13
  3         10/07/2017      04/07/2017         5
  4         26/07/2017      10/07/2017         13
```

Seems like in the real data, I've got correct DaysDifference for ID 2,3,4 except ID 1 because of the null value from its previous row(ID 0) that printing StartDate instead of null EndDate, so it counts incorrectly.

Hope I've provided enough info. :)

Could you please guide me a way to count DaysDifference correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of sql server? Lead and Lag is easy, but for older versions row_number() will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this logic to get the previous date:

```
select t.*,
       lag(coalesce(enddate, startdate), 1) over (order by 1) as newdate 
from t;
```

Then for the difference:

```
select id, enddate, newdate,
       sum(case when c.day not in ('Sat', 'Sun') and c.holiday <> 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as diff
from (select t.*,
             lag(coalesce(enddate, startdate), 1) over (order by 1) as newdate 
      from t
     ) t join
     calendar c
     on c.calendardate >= newdate and c.calendardate <= startdate
group by select id, enddate, newdate;
```